# Convert list of numbers to one integer

Tags: python

Im trying to take in an integer, remove all the odd digits within the integer, and then return this new integer. NO BUILT-INS. the way i did it so far made it into a list, but i need it to output an integer.

```
def rem_odd(integer):
    x = []
    while integer > 0:
        if integer % 2 == 0:
            x = [(integer % 10)] + x
            integer = integer / 10
        else:
            integer = integer / 10
    return x
```

Comment: What do you mean "no built-ins"? I notice you're using quite a few built-in arithmetic operators and control structures, for instance.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you invoke your function with `203` as argument:

```
x = rem_odd(203)
```

you get `x` = `[2, 0]`

This is what you do then:

```
>>> x = [2, 0]
>>> x = [str(a) for a in x]
>>> x
['2', '0']
>>> int(''.join(x))
20
>>>
```

The above is a string manipulation solution. Arithmetically (and not using built-ins), the solution would be:

```
>>> x = rem_odd(203)
>>> p = y = 0
>>> for i in x[::-1]:
...     y += i * (10 ** p)
...     p += 1
...
>>> y
20
```

You traverse the list from right to left, i.e., from units place to the highest power of ten and then multiply each digit with 10 to the power of index.

Comment: I'd go with 'map(str, x)' but its just preference really (sorry about the lack of formatting, on mobile)

Comment: @wnnmaw Neat! I initially looked for a string manipulation based solution. But later settled for a arithmetic based solution since that was the nature of OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

With a loose interpretation of "builtins":

```
def rem_odd(integer):
    return int(''.join(x for x in str(integer) if not x in '13579'))
```

Applying a stricter definition of builtins:

```
def rem_odd(integer):
    r = 0
    mult = 1
    while integer > 0:
        if integer % 2 == 0:
            r = r + mult * (integer % 10)
        integer = integer // 10
        mult *= 10
    return r
```

~

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the other answers here have managed to do this in compliance with "NO BUILT-INS" in the strictest sense, I submit the following extension to Python for OP's use case:

```
/* rem_odd.c */
#include <Python.h>                                                         
#include <math.h>                                                           

static PyObject *                                                           
rem_odd(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)                                     
{ 
    int digit, ix, n, num, result;                                          
    int digits[20];  /* handles up to 2^64 (20 digits) */                   
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &num))                                 
        return NULL;                                                        
    n = num;                                                                
    ix = 0;                                                                 
    while (n > 0) {                                                         
        digit = n % 10;                                                     
        n /= 10;                                                            
        if (digit % 2 == 0)                                                 
            digits[ix++] = digit;                                           
    }
    result = 0;                                                             
    while (ix-- >= 0) {                                                     
        result += (int)(pow(10., ix)) * digits[ix];                         
    }                                                                       
    return Py_BuildValue("i", result);                                      
}                                                                           


static PyMethodDef RemOddMethods[] = {                                      
    {"rem_odd", rem_odd, METH_VARARGS,                                      
    "Remove odd digits from an integer and return another integer."},       
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}                                                   
};


PyMODINIT_FUNC                                                              
initrem_odd(void)                                                           
{                                                                           
    (void) Py_InitModule("rem_odd", RemOddMethods);                         
}
```

Then using `distutils`:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension                                 

rem_odd_module = Extension('rem_odd',                                       
                            sources = ['rem_odd.c'])                        

setup(name='rem_odd', version='1.0',                                        
    description='Remove odd digits from integers -- NO BUILTINS',           
    ext_modules = [rem_odd_module])
```

Example usage (after running `setup.py build` and `setup.py install`):

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Feb 26 2014, 12:01:28) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140206 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from rem_odd import rem_odd
>>> rem_odd(203)
20
>>> rem_odd(9684684)
684684
>>> rem_odd(123456789)
2468
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use built in functions like int() or join(), you can do it like this:

```
def rem_odd(integer):
    x = []
    while integer > 0:
        if integer % 2 == 0:
            x = [(integer % 10)] + x
            integer = integer / 10
        else:
            integer = integer / 10
    res = 0
    digits = len(x)
    for i in range(digits):
        res += x[i] * (10**(digits-i-1))

    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

Integers can be split up into digits raised to a power of 10.

For instance:

- 24 = 2 * 10 + 4
- 256 = 2 * 100 + 5 * 10 + 6

You can utilize the position in your list to determine your current power of 10:

```
def getInt(lst):
    res = 0
    pow = len(lst) - 1

    for el in lst:
        res += el * (10 ** pow)
        pow -= 1

return res
```

Calling `>>> getInt([2,4,8])` now returns: 248

Getting the length of your list without the built-in len would be fairly trivial, as you can just do it recursively.

Comment: Did you edit it? I glanced over it, but I didn't see the arithmetic solution at that point.

Comment: Actually the input is just a number, not a list of numbers.

Comment: I know, this function only takes the list that OP's code produces, and extracts the integer from that list.